# Pulling from aws aurora serverless database through lambda returns [Object Object]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

My intention is to insert to the serverless mysql database through the lambda function, but at the very basic, I find that I am not even able to read from the database. Here is my code on the lambda -

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var rdsdataservice = new AWS.RDSDataService({apiVersion: '2018-08-01'});

var params = {
  secretArn: 'SERCRET_ARN',
  resourceArn: 'RESOURCE_ARN',
  //sql: 'INSERT INTO Users (UserId, GivenName) VALUES (\'USER-17788664349'\, \'theName'\)',
  sql: 'SELECT * from Users',
  database: 'DB',
};
exports.handler = async (event,context) => {
    var data;
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop =false;
        rdsdataservice.executeStatement(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred 
            }
            else {
               data = data;    
            } 
        });
        console.log('RDS Data - '+data);
};
```

Running this soql returns RDS Data - [Object Object]. How do I access the records returned from aws aurora. Also really appreciate if someone could post an example of the insert statement with parameters.

Comment: Was the API documentation for the [response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rdsdataservice/latest/APIReference/API_ExecuteStatement.html#API_ExecuteStatement_ResponseSyntax) not helpful? And if you want to log the response object, one way is to log `JSON.stringify(data)`. Also, all AWS JavaScript SDK async methods have a `.promise()` method so you can use await instead of callbacks. Example: `const rc = await rds.executeStatement(params).promise()`

Comment: @jarmod I just copied the code from the documentation which for some reason was not working for me.

Comment: I didn't see your answer further below. Are you all good now?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I was able to make it work -

```
exports.handler = async (event,context) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop =false;        
    let result = await RDS.executeStatement(params).promise();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
    return 'done';
};
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the issue with the way async function `AWS.RDSDataService.executeStatement` is being executed. Try it with **await** and **promise**. For example:

```
exports.handler = async (event,context) => {
    var data;
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop =false;
        const result = await rdsdataservice.executeStatement(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred 
            }
            else {
               data = data;    
            } 
        }).promise();
        console.log('RDS Data - '+data);
};
```

This way it worked for me. You probably see [Object Object] printed on console log because `var data` has not been assigned to anything actually. I also notice that some of the AWS documentation and the tutorials found elsewhere on the web are not very clear about this. 
 
As for sample code for insert, it should work the same way.

Comment: Hello Pankaj, I tried your code, I still get the same RDS Data - [Object Object]

Comment: What happens if you move the `console.log('RDS Data - '+data);` in to the else block within the callback function?

Comment: Hello Pankaj, I have posted my answer on how I was able to make it work.

Comment: This answer has a few issues. You shouldn't attempt to use both await and an async callback at the same time. Your code has two different variables named `data`. The one in the callback shadows the one in the function scope (so the latter is never initialized). And `data` doesn't print as `[Object Object]` because it's "not been assigned". That's just a default string representation of an actual JavaScript object.